# Can’t Access Files on LAN

Tags: networking, lan, sharing

I have two PCs:

- PC 1: 192.168.0.1
- PC 2: 192.168.0.2

When I test ping, it’s OK like this [Screen Shot](https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/E4nl),
and when I use Remote Desktop, it’s OK too.

But, when I want to access files and type `\\192.168.0.2` into File Explorer,
then I get this error:

[image: Unspecified Error]
(Unspecified Error)

and in Network Panel when I click on DesktopPC (the name of PC 2) I get this error:

[image: Network Path Not Found]
(Network Path Not Found)

Pc 1 windows is 8.1 pc2 is windows 7 and discovery sharing in both are enable and folder was shared already in pc2 !! But i just cant see that in pc1

Comment: (1) We prefer that you phrase your question in the form of a question.  Sure, I guess you want to know why you can’t access your files, and what you need to do to access your files, but you never actually ask. (2) OK, you’re obviously using Windows.  What version?  Please [edit] your question to include this in the body and the tags. (3) Computers don’t automatically share files.  What have you done on DesktopPC to enable file sharing? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) Please don’t post pictures of text.  Error message windows are one thing, since they are visually complex, but I deliberately didn’t embed your first image so you would need to copy the text into your question.  And please also type in the text of the error message windows. (5) Did you notice that your “Network Path Not Found” error window says “DESKTOPPC0212”?  Can you explain this discrepancy?   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: I shared a folder enable sharing enable descovery network i dot these works with remote desktop and get the same error Network Path not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make sure that you enabled network discovery/sharing on both computers. If so, you should be able to access the computer by just scrolling down to the network directory on the left hand side of your file explorer window. If that doesn't work I recommend just using an sftp software like filezilla. The GUI is really easy to work with.

Comment: Can u tell me how to use filezilla for LAN i know how to use it but with ftp of website not in LAN

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I'm completely understanding your question. If both of your computers are on your local area network then you should be able to download the filezilla client, enter the private ip address and all of the corresponding information into the filezilla program you installed. For example (in your case) Host: *192.168.0.2* Username: *your username for PC2* Password: *your password for PC2*

Comment: I run filezilla and all ok so far  i search for 1 mounth for this problem and you solve it thanks alot you are life saver

Comment: No problem glad to help.